# Cannot access class in the Same package in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I am currently working on a Gradle build for a java project but am struggling to figure a couple things out. I resumed to JAVA after years back so if this is a stupid question please help me fellow developers.

```
package dummmy.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cargo{
    String name;
    public Cargo(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCargo(){
        return(this.name);
    }
}
```

I am trying to  implement this class in another class called Station and this is how the Station class looks like.

```
package dummmy.app;
import java.util.List;
import dummmy.app.Cargo;
public class Station{
    String name;
    ArrayList<Cargo> cargo;

    public Station(String name, ArrayList<Cargo> cargo){
        this.name = name;
        this.cargo = cargo;
    }

    public void getCargo(){
      System.out.print(cargo);
    }

    public static void main() {
      
    }
    
}
```

I cannot understand why during compilation, this error shows up?

```
Station.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    ArrayList<Cargo> cargo;
    ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class Station
Station.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    ArrayList<Cargo> cargo;
              ^
  symbol:   class Cargo
  location: class Station
Station.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    public Station(String name, ArrayList<Cargo> cargo){
                                ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class Station
Station.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    public Station(String name, ArrayList<Cargo> cargo){
                                          ^
  symbol:   class Cargo
  location: class Station
4 errors
```

Comment: Note you don't need `import` statements for classes in the same package (though I'm not sure if having them would cause an error or not).

Comment: You've imported list but not ArrayList, import and it will be fixed.

Comment: @Slaw A "pointless" import is not an error, nor a warning. Of course, many linter tools would mark em off as suspicious. try it; just stick e.g. `import java.lang.*; or `import com.foo.myownpackage.SomeTypeInMyPackage;` at the top.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I know "pointless" imports are not an error. I wasn't sure if importing a class in the "current package" was an error. And yes, I could have tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems in your code.

You've imported `java.util.List`, however, you have failed to import `java.util.ArrayList`.

Also, your Cargo class has no `package` statement, whereas your `Station` class does, which trivially means they aren't in the same package.

Comment: Even after putting it in the same package that is dummy.app, it is showing the same error.

Comment: @TanayUpreti Perform a ”clean” and “rebuild” operation in your IDE and/or Gradle.

Comment: @TanayUpreti Did you fix *both* problems described in the Answer?